# Find and solve a recurrence for the number of n-digit ternary sequences with no consecutive digits being equal.

Tags: combinatorics

I have so far than a1=3, a2=6, and a3=12. So the number of ways doubles as n increases by one. However, I do not know how to put this into a recurrence relationship. 
I also know the three cases: 
When sequence starts with 0- the next digit cannot be a 1. So, there are two choices. The same goes for when sequence begins with a 1 and 2. 
However, I do not know how to put this relationship into a recurrence form.

Comment: If you have an $n$-digit ternary sequence with no consecutive digits equal, and you want to extend it to an $n+1$-digit ternary sequence with no consecutive digits equal, how many ways can you do so?

Comment: I understand that there are two ways. So is the relationship an= 2a(n-1)?